# Hexadecimal to decimal converter

Tags: python

How could I make my program more efficient? Right now it is filled with if statements.

```
import copy
def hexadecimal(a):

   z = a.replace('0b','')

   y = z.rjust(8,'0')
   list1 = list(y)
   newlist = []
   for i in range(1,5):
      nig = list1.pop(0)
      newlist.append(nig)       

   if newlist == ['0','0','0','0']:
      valuenew = ''
   if newlist == ['0','0','0','1']:
      valuenew = '1'
   if newlist == ['0','0','1','0']:
      valuenew = '2'
   if newlist == ['0','1','0','0']:
      valuenew = '4'
   if newlist == ['1','0','0','0']:
      valuenew = '8'
   if newlist == ['0','0','1','1']:
      valuenew = '3'
   if newlist == ['0','1','1','1']:
      valuenew = '7'
   if newlist == ['0','1','0','1']:
      valuenew = '5'
   if newlist == ['0','1','1','0']:
      valuenew = '6'
   if newlist == ['1','0','0','1']:
      valuenew = '9'
   if newlist == ['1','0','1','0']:
      valuenew = 'A'
   if newlist == ['1','0','1','1']:
      valuenew = 'B'
   if newlist == ['1','1','0','0']:
      valuenew = 'C'
   if newlist == ['1','1','0','1']:
      valuenew = 'D'
   if newlist == ['1','1','1','0']:
      valuenew = 'E'
   if newlist == ['1','1','1','1']:
      valuenew = 'F'

   if list1 == ['0','0','0','0']:
      valuenew1 = ''
   if list1 == ['0','0','0','1']:
      valuenew1 = '1'
   if list1 == ['0','0','1','0']:
      valuenew1 = '2'
   if list1 == ['0','1','0','0']:
      valuenew1 = '4'
   if list1 == ['1','0','0','0']:
      valuenew1 = '8'
   if list1 == ['0','0','1','1']:
      valuenew1 = '3'
   if list1 == ['0','1','1','1']:
      valuenew1 = '7'
   if list1 == ['0','1','0','1']:
      valuenew1 = '5'    
   if list1 == ['0','1','1','0']:
      valuenew1 = '6'    
   if list1 == ['1','0','0','1']:
      valuenew1 = '9'    
   if list1 == ['1','0','1','0']:
      valuenew1 = 'A'    
   if list1 == ['1','0','1','1']:
      valuenew1 = 'B'    
   if list1 == ['1','1','0','0']:
      valuenew1 = 'C'    
   if list1 == ['1','1','0','1']:
      valuenew1 = 'D'    
   if list1 == ['1','1','1','0']:
      valuenew1 = 'E'    
   if list1 == ['1','1','1','1']:
      valuenew1 = 'F'

   print(valuenew + valuenew1)            

a = str(bin(int(input('enter a number'))))

hexadecimal(a)
```

The program is only meant to convert a binary up to 8 bits

Comment: Welcome to SO. Consider posting your question to codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: Assign the values 1, 2, 4, 8 to 4 positions. Loop though and build up a sum between 0  and 15. Use a dict to look up, say, "F" from 15.

Comment: I think you try to convert binary to hexadecimal.

Answer (score 2):

> How could I make my program more efficient?

You could simply use the [`format()`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/functions.html#format) or [`hex()`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/functions.html#hex) function to convert an integer to a hex string:

```
>>> format(255, 'X')
'FF'
>>> hex(255)
'0xff'
```

Answer (score 0):

Python already has something built in for what you want `hex()`. However if you're hellbent on making your own, I've made some adjustments to your code:

**(1)** Since python doesn't have a switch statement the best you can do is to try to use a `dict` instead; I've also introduced a `hex_digit` function that is basically just referencing the value you need from `HEX_DIGIT` (you don't really need it but it abstracts that part if you need to replace it in the future)

**(2)** Adding some logic to your *padding* so it won't just be for **8 bit length numbers**

```
HEX_DIGITS = {
  '0000': '',
  '0001': '1',
  '0010': '2',
  '0011': '3',
  '0100': '4',
  '0101': '5',
  '0110': '6',
  '0111': '7',
  '1000': '8',
  '1001': '9',
  '1010': 'A',
  '1011': 'B',
  '1100': 'C',
  '1101': 'D',
  '1110': 'E',
  '1111': 'F',
}

def hex_digit(val):
  print('Converting: ' , val)
  return HEX_DIGITS.get(val, '')

def hexadecimal(a):
  z = a.replace('0b','')
  len_z = len(z)

  # Add padding if len not a factor of 4
  if len_z % 4 != 0:
    full_length = len_z + (4 - (len_z % 4))
    z = z.rjust(full_length, '0')

  split_vals = [
    hex_digit(z[idx:idx+4])
    for idx in range(0,len(z),4)
  ]
  print("Hex value: {}".format("".join(split_vals)))

a = str(bin(int(input('Enter a number: '))))

hexadecimal(a)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can convert an arbitrary string literal that represents a number to an integer with given base and then convert that integer to a string.

```
>> b = '0b01001'
>> format(int(b, 2), 'X')
'9'
>> b = '1001'
>> format(int(b, 2), 'X')
'9'
```

---

**CODE**

```
def hexadecimal(a):
    return format(bin(a, 2), 'X')  # You could also print it
```